# How to check when Imgur Token will expire?

Tags: imgur

I'm making REST request to Imgur API to get new token (refresh_token), however I can't get any kind of information about token expire date from it. It has JSON format and there is a field "expired_in" but it value is always 315360000 and I have no idea what that mean. For sure it's not a date, because all tokens has the same value there.

Below is response from Imgur with new token:

`{
    "access_token":"5c3118ebb73fbb275945ab340be60b610a3216d6",
    "refresh_token":"d36b474c95bb9ee54b992c7c34fffc2cc343d0a7",
    "expires_in":315360000,
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "account_username":"saponifi3d"
}`

Acording to [Imgur API docs](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#authorization-and-oauth) token will expire after 1 month, but where can I check how much time left? There have to be a way to verify that...

Comment: It's an elapsed time between you getting the token and it expiring, that's why it's always the same. You also need to keep the timestamp of the token being generated.

Comment: So I can't get the expire date from it. Only way is to store date of token creation plus one month as a expire date?

Comment: So 'expires_in' desribes how many seconds this token will be valid.